# Updating and appending xml at a time

Tags: java, xml

I have a template XML

```xml
<Students>
    <list>
        <schoolName>XYZ</schoolName>
        <student>
            <name></name>
            <rollno></rollno>
        </student>
    </list>
</Students>
```

Also I have a list of students from where i need to add the name and roll no and append the xml with same attribute  depending on the size of the list.
REquirement is -in case i have only 1 student i just need to update the attribute with the values in list and if list size is more than 1 it should append to the student tag.

```xml
<Students>
    <list>
        <schoolName>XYZ</schoolName>
        <student>
            <name>AA</name>
            <rollno>1</rollno>
        <student>
        <student>
            <name>BB</name>
            <rollno>2</rollno>
        </student>
    </list>
</Students>
```

I am not able to do so
I tried using this code

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse("student.xml");
    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

    Collection<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();

    for (Student st: students) {
        // server elements
        Element newStudnet = document.createElement("student");

        Element name = document.createElement("name");
        name.appendChild(document.createTextNode("B");
        newStudnet.appendChild(name);

        Element rollno= document.createElement("rollno");
        rollno.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2");
        newStudnet.appendChild(rollno);

        root.appendChild(newStudnet);
    }

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult("student.xml");
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

If I do this student tag is added at the last not next to the first student tag like this

```xml
<Students>
    <list>
        <schoolName>XYZ</schoolName>
        <student>
            <name></name>
            <rollno></rollno>
        </student>
    </list>
</Students>

<student>
    <name>B</name>
    <rollno>2</rollno>
</student>
```

Can someone help to help me finf a way . I have a list of students which gets updated with names and roll no and i want to append the xml with the entries.

Comment: Is the code in your question code the code you are running? I don't see where newStudnet is declared.

Comment: @tgdavies edited please check

Comment: You still have syntax errors in your code. Just copy and paste the running code.

Answer (score 0):

You're appending your student to the root of the XML tree:

```
root.appendChild(newStudnet);
```

Which is why it ends up appended to the root.

You need to find the list and append it to that:

```
Node list = document.getElementsByTagName("list").item(0);
list.appendChild(newStudnet);
```

You should do some error checking in case `<list>` is missing, or there is more than one.

Incidentally, having a list which contains two different entity types (schoolName and student) is asking for trouble -- you are depending on the order of the entities to associate a school name with a subset of the students.

Instead you should have:

```
<schools>
  <school>
    <name>MIT</name>
    <students>
      <student>
         ...
      </student>
    </students>
  </school>
  ...
</schools>
```